# Change Virtualbox default VM folder with Ansible

Tags: virtualbox, ansible

I'm trying to set up a computer that will act as a server using Ansible. Basically this works quite well but I got one command that I cannot get to work. I want to install Virtualbox and change the default folder where the VMs are stored. This can be done with `vboxmanage setproperty machinefolder /path/to/folder`. I know that this command works. I used it on another machine which I installed without Ansible. Works as expected there.

This is my (shortened) playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Caprica Playbook
  hosts: all
  vars:
    default_username: starbuck
    default_password: start123
    vm_folder: "/home/{{ default_username }}/vagrantboxes"
  become: true
  tasks:

    # create + config default user
    # --> ansible code here ...

    # ssh config
    # --> ansible code here ...

    # config
    # --> ansible code here ...

    # install basic packages
    # --> ansible code here ...

    # install docker
    # --> ansible code here ...

    #install vagrant + virtualbox

    - name: Install Virtualbox
      apt:
        pkg:
          - virtualbox
          - virtualbox-qt
          - virtualbox-dkms
        state: latest
        update_cache: true

    - name: Set virtual machine folder
      ansible.builtin.shell: "vboxmanage setproperty machinefolder {{ vm_folder }}"
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash

    - name: Install Vagrant
      ansible.builtin.shell: |
        curl https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/2.2.19/vagrant_2.2.19_x86_64.deb --output vagrant.deb
        sudo dpkg -i vagrant.deb
        rm vagrant.deb
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash

    - name: Install Vagrant plugins
      ansible.builtin.shell: |
        vagrant plugin install vagrant-cachier
        vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
        vagrant plugin install vagrant-docker-compose
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
```

The troublesome part is the "Set virtual machine folder" section. When I run this playbook it seems like this is completely ignored all the time.

I composed a Chef InSpec test to check my Ansible installation. Checking for the correct VM folder always returns an error.

```
x  Bash command vboxmanage list systemproperties | grep folder stdout is expected to cmp == "Default machine folder:          /home/starbuck/virtualmachines"
     
expected: Default machine folder:          /home/starbuck/virtualmachines
     got: Default machine folder:          /home/starbuck/VirtualBox VMs
```

It's always returning the default path.

Anyone got an idea why the "Set virtual machine folder" section does not work?

Comment: I'm sure that if you issue your test command as root user you will find that root stores its vms in the folder you want. You are using `become: true` globally on your play hence all commands are run as root whereas you want to run `setproperty` for virtualbox as user `starbuck`. If you already connect as this user, just add `become: false` on your task. If you connect with an other deploy user, then add `become_user: starbuck` to the task.

Comment: That's exactly it. Thanks for your help. `become_user: starbuck` works. Hint: I also had to install acl package (seems to be missing from newer ubuntu releases). Without acl I got the ansible error `failed to set permissions on the temporary files ansible needs to create when becoming an unprivileged user`. Installing acl fixed this.